# How to get the value of an associate array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
    $this->uploaders = array(
        'yt' => 'Youtube',
        'hl' => 'Hulu',
        'fd' => 'Funny or Die'
    );
```

In my script the following:

```
substr($uploader->external_id, 0, 2);
```

will always return either 'yt', 'hl' or 'fd'. I need to do a check to see which one it matches and return the value from the above array.

For example if `substr($uploader->external_id, 0, 2)` returned "yt" I need it to return "Youtube". How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
$type = substr($uploader->external_id, 0, 2);
$longName = $this->uploaders[$type];
```

$longName will contain 'Youtube' if substr($uploader->external_id, 0, 2) contains 'yt'

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
echo $this->uploaders[ substr($uploader->external_id, 0, 2) ];
```